# Invoke the Inbuilt video player inside a layout

Tags: android, video

I need to invoke the inbuilt the default video player inside an inner layout and my layout
 looks like some what below.

[image]

onclick of the button1 i want to invoke the video player inside the layout(in red color)

by the below code i can play the video(it opens a new view) but I want to show the video inside the layout only

```
  Uri video = Uri.parse("/sdcard/video/123.mp4");
     Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
     intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
     intent.setDataAndType(video, "video/*");
     startActivity(intent);
```

Any help is always appreciated,Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Set up `VideoView` control in red area and pass `sdcard` path to that `VideoView` on Button cliked.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    Button b1;
    VideoView myVideoView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        myVideoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.myvideoview);
        b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                myVideoView.setVideoPath("Your sdcard video path");
                myVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
                myVideoView.requestFocus();
                myVideoView.start();

            }
        });
    }
```

also add permission for read sdcard(storage) in `Manifest.xml`

For more information about  play video from sdcard 
http://android-coding.blogspot.in/2011/03/using-videoview-to-play-mp4-from-sdcard.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer,but i dont want to use videoview.

Comment: Then want you want to implement?

Comment: You can also use SurfaceView and MediaPlayer.

Comment: I want to invoke the inbuilt video player only. not using surface view or videoview.i want to invoke it using  the code which i have shown above in a layout.is it possible?